# How to compile dojo themes in windows using nodejs?

Tags: dojo

I download the dojo source with the themes and compiler and i tried to compile it using node.js

and followed the instruction below, but was unable to compile it in pc environment?

Can some help?

http://davidwalsh.name/dijit-theme

http://nodejs.org/#

```
C:\Downloads\dojo-release-1.7.3-src\dojo-release-1.7.3-src\dijit\themes\claro>node compile.js

Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.
    at Function.Module._compile.Object.defineProperty.get (module.js:386:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Downloads\dojo-release-1.7.3-src\dojo-release-1.7.3-src\util\less\ind
ex.js:5:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Downloads\dojo-release-1.7.3-src\dojo-release-1.7.3-src\dijit\themes\
claro\compile.js:8:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an outdated version of LESS with a newer version of node.

dojo-release-1.7.3-src comes bundled with LESS 1.1.3, released early 2011.

Replace `util/less` with a [more recent version](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/archive/v1.3.3.zip) of LESS.

---

Alternatively, all `compile.js` [is doing](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.3/dojo-release-1.7.3/dijit/themes/claro/compile.js) is running the LESS parser against all of the LESS files in the theme directory.  You could install the LESS command line tools (`npm install -g less`) and invoke [`lessc`](http://lesscss.org/#usage) on the LESS files manually.